# How to create a feature burndown chart in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

The Azure DevOps documentation that describes [Burndown and Burnup Charts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-burndown-burnup-widgets?view=azure-devops) describes the following types of burndown charts (quotations are from the link above):

1. "A **sprint burndown** tracks the sprint backlog completion by end of the sprint"
2. "A **release burndown** tracks the release backlog completion by the end of the release"
   [image]
3. "A **bug burndown** chart to track completion of a set of bugs by a certain date"
   [image]

However, I would like to implement a **feature burndown** where the X-axis is a sprint or date (same as either of the 2 charts above) and the y-axis is either the count of the number of stories + bugs or the sum of the points. Most importantly, this feature burndown chart would show *only the children of a specific feature item*, such as this list of 4:

[image]

How can I please generate this feature burndown chart described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it's **not available** right now. What you are looking for is a filter such as below:

[image]

We already had a raised feature request in our Develop Community user voice site:

> Epic / Feature Burndown Chart
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/964703/epic-feature-burndown-chart.html

You could kindly vote up it and monitor the status, our PM will review them.

Answer (score 0):

Our Dev teams are moving from JIRA to DevOps and also asked for this, as you can do this in JIRA.

As a workaround you could put a tag on each User Story to identify the Parent, eg "Feature 4" then filter on that. You could also put a tag to identify the Epic, that enables a Burndown chart to be created on User Stories for an Epic, similar to that in JIRA.

Tagging can either be done manually or a Power Automate flow created to do it on a schedule.

[image: Burndown Chart Configuration]

If you select Backlog you can also include Bugs if they are tagged in the same way:

[image: Backlog Burndown Chart]